# Confusion in proof for writing Poincares series in terms of Kloosterman sum

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

I am currently self reading " Spectral theory of Riemann zeta function" by Yoichi Motohashi. The example is in first chapter and of poincare series. I am not able to justify from 1.1.5 to the next line. Actually I don't know what does mean by classifying summands according to h (mod l). Any help/Hint would be appreciated. I am stuck here since yesterday.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the summary has very often the expression $h/l$ , it is sensible to ask: how can I divide this fraction in integral part and fractional part? We can also hope, since some functions over there are periodic (e.g. $\exp( i\cdot) $) that things with the same fractional part will contribute in a similar fashion.

Hence we set $h = l n + h'$, with $h' = 1, \ldots, l $ and $n= - \infty, \ldots, +\infty$. The new $h'$ is the "classification $\pmod{l}$ " of the summand relative to $h$. Recall that $h$ has to be comprime with $l$, so that $ 1= (ln+h', l) = (h', l) $: the classification index has to be coprime with $l$. If $g(l, h) $ is your summand, you can then write

$$\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\sum_{h=-\infty, (h, l) =1}^{+\infty} g(l, h) = \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \sum_{h'=1}^{l} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} g(l, nl+h') $$

Comment: Thank you so much Andrea Sir for the help. We can say the sum on the left hand side is equal to right hand side because we have bijection between the integers h satisfying (h,l)=1 with the set containing pair of integers (h',n). Am I correct in this reasoning?

Comment: Yes, beside the fact that you have to include the condition $(h', l) =1$. Note that very often there is an abuse of notation in index changing, so that $h'$ is called also $h$ . Personally, I try to avoid this kind of practices (we have tons of letters, why repeating??)

Comment: Ok Sir thanks again, Got it.. Can you give me a hint in the next step that how they applying Poisson sum formula to the last sum?

Comment: Maybe this can be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula