# Application of Poisson summation formula

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, poisson-summation-formula

I am currently self reading " Spectral theory of Riemann zeta function" by Yoichi Motohashi. The example is in first chapter and of poincare series. I want to know how the Poisson sum formula on the last sum led to the final equation. I dont need any exact answer. Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Edit 1:
[Confusion in proof for writing Poincares series in terms of Kloosterman sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4051061)
This question I asked earlier today related to this topic.

[image]

Comment: You have asked the same question 8 hours ago (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4051061) under a different title ; you have had an answer that you have validated. Why asking again without mentionning this previous question and its answer ? This is against the policy of this site.

Comment: Mr Jean, With due respect,Please dont see only  the image. Just read my question here.

Comment: In any case, you should have mentionned the previous **very connected** question.

Comment: Ok Sir, Thank you for the info. I am editing it rn.

Comment: @JeanMarie  Is it okay now Sir ?

Comment: Fine. Thank you for the acknowledgement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please type your questions in mathjax, more readable and easier for us to copy/paste. $$f(x+iy)=\sum_n |x+iy+h/l+n|^{-2s}\exp(\frac{-2i\pi m}{ l^2(x+iy+h/l+n)})$$ is smooth $1$-periodic, it is equal to its Fourier series $$\sum_k \exp(2i\pi k x) c_k(y)$$ where $$c_k(y)=\int_0^1 f(x+iy)\exp(-2i\pi k x) dx$$ $$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x+iy+h/l|^{-2s}\exp(\frac{-2i\pi m}{ l^2(x+iy+h/l)})\exp(-2i\pi k x) dx$$

What do you get then?

Comment: Ok Sir, I will post questions in mathjax from next time. Answer to your question: When we found the value of $ c_k(y)$ then by Poisson summation formula f(0+ iy) = sum of all $ c_k(y)$. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes but you want $f(z)$ for all $z$ so plug the Fourier series directly and see if you can get the book's formula (it seems they did $x=\xi y$)

Comment: Thanks for help Sir, I am able to do it now.